# Commutative cipher recognizing proper decryption?

Tags: cryptography

In theory, let's say I'm using a commutative symmetrical cipher to create my own kind of encrypted file. I know that an encrypted rar/zip would do what I'm thinking of, but I'm looking to understand the under the hood details. If I just encrypt the file with no meta data, then how can I know when I decrypt it that it's properly decrypted?

One approach I thought of was to place the key used at the front of the file and then encrypt the key along with the file. When I decrypt, I can compare the decryption key with the beginning of the file and know if it worked, but I'm uncomfortable with actually placing the key inside the file.

Another idea would be placing a static section of data at the beginning of the file, but that can be used as an indicator when trying to brute force the file to when a collision in keys (or the actual key) is discovered if anybody knows the static section of data and I don't like security through obscurity.

My last thought is to include the hash of the initial unencrypted file, but for large files that can slow down the process. With this approach, I have to hash and encrypt the file and that seems inefficient. I'm hoping there's a better technique.

What would be the best approach to verify that an file that was encrypted with a commutative symmetrical cipher was decrypted successfully (without having the original file to compare to)?

Comment: if you have two commutative ciphers, A and B, where A(...) and B(...) encrypt and A'(...) and B'(...) decrypts than A'(B(A(data))) is equivalent to B(data). Basically any cipher that works with the 3-pass protocol. Read the 4th paragraph here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-pass_protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a header with a well defined, but random format. One standard way to do this is with random data and cryptographic hashes (pseudo-code follows):

```
byte[] header = new byte[64];
header[0..31] = RandomBytes(32); // 32 cryptographically random bytes
header[32..63] = SHA256(header[0..31]); //Hash of your random data
```

This gives 64 bytes of high entropy data. There is no way this can be used crib for brute-forcing the encryption. To validate you have the proper key, just decrypt the header and check to make sure that the second 32 bytes are a valid SHA256 hash of the first.

Comment: Yes it can, however any non completely random plaintext can be to check for proper decryption. The important factor is that it eliminates the known-plaintext attacks which are possible with static (or even semi-static) headers.

Answer (score 1):

I would still recommend storing a hash or checksum. If you put it at the end of the encrypted data, you can generate the checksum as you read the file during the encryption, so it doesn't require any extra passes through the file. (There will be CPU overhead for the checksum, but that'll be minimal. You don't need to use something as expensive as SHA for this purpose; CRC32 will do.)

The checksum will help detect errors in transit. If a single bit in the encrypted data is altered, the decrypted data past that point will probably be garbage. A magic header won't detect that, but a checksum will.

Comment: I agree. Both a final checksum/hash and a header should be used as they detect different things. The header allows you to quickly identify if you've got the correct key, while the checksum/hash detects corruption/tampering.

Answer (score 0):

There are cipher modes like [CCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode) that provide integrity. I'm not sure how they would fit with your requirement for commutativity.